# Addition of angular form controls value is in html

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-forms

```
 <pre> {{((itemInfoForm.controls['quantity'].value) + (selected_item.quantity))}}</pre>
```

output : 10+10=1010

expected result: 10+10=20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create one method and pass parameter along with and get return as number like this

```
 <pre> 
  {{changeType(itemInfoForm.controls['quantity'].value) + changeType(selected_item.quantity)}}
 </pre>

 ......//and in your controller side write function like this
 changeType(val){
    return +(val);
  }
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zIwFZglcEGCm76DThHra?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, convert them to numbers using parseInt

```
{{parseInt(itemInfoForm.controls['quantity'].value) + parseInt(selected_item.quantity)}}
```

Comment: not working ERROR TypeError: co.parseInt is not a function

Comment: Use {{Number.parseInt(object1)+Number.parseInt(object2)}}

Comment: not working TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseInt' of undefined

Comment: can you post item 1 and item 2 object value

Comment: It's itemInfoForm.controls['quantity'].value